# Word VSTO - Unable to set the ForeColor.RGb property for an illustration(graphics) object

Tags: ms-word, vsto

1. Open Word O365 on desktop
2. Goto Insert > Icons > Illustrations
3. Choose the bus illustration

[image]

Using the following code, I'm unable to set the RGB property of forecolor

```
InlineShape ish = document.InlineShapes[1];
ish.Fill.Solid();
ish.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 16777215; //RGB White
```

The RGB property is 0 before and after I set the value. However, it is interesting to note that the color of the bus changes on the Word application. But not in the debugger.

[image]

I would like to check the RGB color value of the ForeColor before I set it. How do I fix this or work around this? Is there anything wrong in the way I'm accessing the properties? This works for all icons in Word.

Comment: To get the color of the icons parts, ungroup twice or use _Graphics Format>Convert to  Shape_ (Sorry, I don't know the C# commands). That turns the icon into native Office shapes that can be accessed by code to get the color.

Comment: @JohnKorchok : I'm able to ungroup the object only once. Essentially, it does the sa,me thing as Convert to shape for this illustration object. I don't want to convert the illustration to shape. I'm interested in knowing how the color changed to white without change in ish.Fill.ForeColor.RGB property. For Word to render the object in white, some property must have changed from yellow to white. I would like to confirm the value of that property before modifying it.

Comment: The color change when you apply a fill is misleading you. To get the color of the bus, you need to find the fill of that shape in the ShapeRange that is the grouped object. I don't know the C# equivalent of ShapeRange. But you can't get that with VBA until you have converted the object to a Microsoft Office drawing object by ungrouping it. Perhaps C# has some magic method to get that information from an embedded SVG, but I doubt it.